# How to make Angular Client to inform Identity Server which login method to use?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, angular10, oidc-client-js

I am using IdentityServer 4 with an Angular 10 client that uses [OIDC Client JS](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki):

To redirect a user for signin I am calling signinRedirect on the Angular's client:

```
UserManager.signinRedirect(args)
```

That redirects to IdentityServer 4 [AcccountController's Login](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/main/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L59) action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl) {
  var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);
  if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly) {
    // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
    return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", new { scheme = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

**Question**

I have Google and Facebook External Providers configured in Identity Server.

How to use `signinRedirect` and inform IdentityServer to use an external provider, like Google, for login?

I would like to bypass the login page in IdentityServer where there are 3 options:

1. Login with Username and Password
2. Login with Google
3. Login with Facebook

So the Angular Client would inform Identity Server which login method should be used.

**Update**

After some research it seems there is a way in the spec to specify which provider to user:

```
UserManager.signinRedirect({ acr_values: 'IdP:Google' }));
```

Then on the [AccountController's BuildLoginViewModelAsync](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/main/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L240) there is the following:

```
var context = await _interactionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);

if (request?.IdP != null && await _schemeProvider.GetSchemeAsync(request.IdP) != null) {

  var local = request.IdP == IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider;
```

If I am not wrong the `IF` condition and following code is to check which Login Provider should be used: Local or one of the External providers configured.

I debugged `context` and got the following:

[image]

The AcrValues is parsed but the property IdP is not defined.

Shouldn't AcrValues be the way to solve this? What am I missing?

Comment: This is old but might help someone else. If IdP string is empty in the context object, make sure that case of the supplied IdP ("Google" in the above example) matches in both, configuration stored in settings in the client app and client configuration stored in IdP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to send a message to the identity provider using oidc-client by using the `args` parameter of `signinRedirect` method.

If you take a look at [oidc-client-js/src/SigninRequest.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/b241a97e9b73315a0cb45bdf787c1c7e746cb048/src/SigninRequest.js#L8) from their github repository, you can see that you can supply the following optional parameters to the aforementioned method:

- `data`,
- `prompt`,
- `display`,
- `max_age`,
- `ui_locales`,
- `id_token_hint`,
- `login_hint`,
- `acr_values`,
- `resource`,
- `response_mode`,
- `request`,
- `request_uri`,
- `extraQueryParams`,
- `request_type`,
- `client_secret`,
- `extraTokenParams`,
- `skipUserInfo`

Later in the code, on line 75 of this file version, they have this:

```js
for(let key in extraQueryParams){
  url = UrlUtility.addQueryParam(url, key, extraQueryParams[key])
}
```

which means they allow devs to use `extraQueryParams` to supply custom parameters.

Now assuming your custom message parameter might be called `useExternalProvider`, you should be able to call `signInRedirect` like this:

```js
UserManager.signinRedirect({ 
  extraQueryParams: {
    useExternalProvider: "google"
  }});
```

To access this parameter on your IdentityServer, find the line which calls `GetAuthorizationContextAsync` and inspect the protocol message parameters like this:

```cs
var context = await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
var externalProviderToUse = context.Parameters.Get("useExternalProvider");
```

It is usually in `BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)` method if you used their QuickStart.

From there you can retrieve the external login parameters from database, or from wherever you keep those parameters from, and instead of redirecting users to the login page, redirect them directly to your `ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)` using `RedirectToAction`.

**EDIT**

If you want to use the `acr_values` parameter for this and later in IdentityServer authorization context want to use the `Idp` property, you can call:

```js
// "idp:" is case sensitive
UserManager.signinRedirect({ acr_values: 'idp:Google' }));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive explanation. In the meanwhile I did some more research and found out that AcrValues should maybe be used for this case instead of extraQueryParams. However, I was not able to make it work as the IdP is not defined in the context. What do you think? I just added an Update to my question.

Comment: @MiguelMoura the prefix needs to be "idp:" - case sensitive. I have updated the answer